# Subir imagenes y datos adicionales desde ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hola buena tarde chicos miren tengo una duda, he podido subir imagenes y cualquier tipo de archivos con ajax ya que pues he estado haciendo pruebas pero lo que quiero ahora es poder subir imagenes y poder nombrarlas con el mismo formulario que ocupo para subir la imagen

les anexo el codigo que uso y ustedes me dicen donde anexo el nombre o como puedo hacer que lo detecte

```
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src='js/toastr.min.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/toastr.min.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Subir archivos prueba 3!</h1>
  <form class="form_example" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" id='nombre_arc' name="nombre_arc"></input>
    <input type="file" id='archvioID' name="archvioID">
    <input type="button" id="subir" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Cargar">

  </form>




  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

este es el JQUERY

```
  <script>

    $('#subir').on('click',function(){
        var miArchvio = $("#archvioID").prop('files')[0];
        var nombre_img = $("#nombre_arc").val();
        var formData_example = new FormData($(".form_example")[0]);
        formData_example.append('archvioID',miArchvio);
        console.log(miArchvio)
        $.ajax({
        url: "./php/valida_carga_server.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData_example,
            }) .done(function(respuesta){
            toastr.success(respuesta, 'Notificación:', {
                "progressBar": true
            })
        })
       
    });
</script>
```

este es el codigo de php

```
 <?php
        $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archvioID']['name'];
        $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archvioID']['type'];
        $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archvioID']['size'];
        $Carpeta = "../Expedientes/";
    
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archvioID']['tmp_name'],$Carpeta.$nombre_archivo)){
            echo "El archivo ha sido cargado correctamente.";
            } else {
            echo "Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.";
            }
    
    ?>
```

Y el resultado de este codigo es exitoso pero aun quiero nombrar la imagen sin tener que crear variables de sesion en el php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y qué nombre quieres ponerle?

Comment: quiero agregar un nombre con el formulario desde un imput ahi lo muestro en la imagen y en el html

Comment: Muestra el código de valida_carga_server.php

Comment: esta hasta abajo en la pregunta

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar inputs hidden para renombrar? Que nombre quieres ponerle?¿ Si explicas mejor lo que quieres conseguir podremos ayudarte.

Comment: como se usan los inputs hidden? y si me gustaria llenar un formulario con x informacion y que puedas guardar una imagen cuando le des en guardar registro que se mande todo el formulario junto con la imagen pero desde ajax por que en la forma tradicional ya lo he hecho pero aun me falta ese paso en ajax...